# Yii2 custom client validation with ajax rendering in modal

Tags: php, yii2

I have a model with a custom validation method. For testing it always returns an error message.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
     ...
        ['staff_ids', 'each', 'rule' =>  ['string']],
        [['staff_ids'], 'validateStaffIds'],
     ...
    ];
}

public function validateStaffIds($attribute, $params, $validator) {
    $this->addError($attribute, 'There is an error in the staff ids');
}
```

In the view.php is the modal element

```
<p>      
    <?= Html::button('Add Ensemble Staff',
            ['value' => Url::to(['ensemble/add', 'id' => $model->id]), 
             'title' => 'Adding New Ensemble Staff',
             'class' => 'showModalButton btn btn-primary']); 
    ?>
</p>

<?php
    Modal::begin([
        'closeButton' => [
              'label' => 'x',
        ],
        'headerOptions' => ['id' => 'modalHeader'],
        'id' => 'modal',
        'size' => 'modal-lg',
    ]);
    echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";
    Modal::end();
?>
```

The js code which fires everything up...

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.showModalButton', function(){

        if ($('#modal').data('bs.modal').isShown) {
            $('#modal').find('#modalContent')
                    .load($(this).attr('value'));
        } else {
            //if modal isn't open; open it and load content
            $('#modal').modal('show')
                    .find('#modalContent')
                    .load($(this).attr('value'));      
        }

        //dynamiclly set the header for the modal
        ...
    });
});
```

And the `ensemble` controller which handles the `add` action

```
public function actionAdd($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    // in the post ( 'ensembleStaff_ids' => [0 => '2']); where the id actually is staff_id
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' =>  $id]);
    } else {
        return $this->renderAjax('add', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And the form which is injected by the js into the model (`Url::to(['ensemble/add', 'id' => $model->id]),` )

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'add-theater-stuff-form']); ?>  

<?= $form->field($model, 'staff_ids')->widget(Select2::className(), [
       'model' => $model,
       'data' => ArrayHelper::map(app\models\TheaterStaff::find()->where(['theater_id' => $model->theater_id])->all(), 'staff_id', 'staff.fullname'),
       'options' => [
           'multiple' => true,
           'prompt' => 'Ensemble Staff',
       ], 
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'tags' => true
        ]
   ]); ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Add', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Clicking on the `Add Ensemble Staff` Button works fine and brings up the modal window. The form itself works fine so far; also the default validation works. Even the custom validation is called, but return $this->renderAjax(...) isn't load in the modal window anymore; it is separately.

A [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiX7j.jpg) showing the modal loaded, the result after submit and a modal with default validation.

I found a similar problem [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/4768). But adding an id to the form, doesn't solve the problem. So how to get the default validation showing up properly in the modal window? Does anyone have a clue?

**Solution**

Thanks for the response. For me the solution was:
Enable ajax in the form

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'add-ensemble-stuff-form', 'enableAjaxValidation' => true]); ?>
```

And to add the following logic in the controller

```
public function actionAdd($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return ActiveForm::validate($model);
        } else {
            // in the post ( 'ensembleStaff_ids' => [0 => '2']); where the id actually is staff_id
            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' =>  $id]);
            } else {
                return $this->renderAjax('add', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try `enableAjaxValidation => true` in form options.

Comment: @InsaneSkull Yes that worked! I really thought i tried this already ... hrrr .. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }else{/* your code */}
```

add this in controller `use yii\web\Response`

Comment: added it; doesn't change anything; request->isAjax returns false; is my js not complete?

Comment: yes.. I missed that. Load the view file using ajax.

Comment: The `form` is in your `modal`?

Comment: yes, the form is in the modal. Isn't the view file loaded via ajax here?                   .load($(this).attr('value'))

Comment: try `$form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'add-theater-stuff-form', 'enableAjaxValidation' => true])`

Comment: @S Rana yes that did the trick! @Insane Skull already mentioned it; thanks for your help!